# How to update the content of td using js more efficently?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, getelementbyid

I have a to write an html page, where you have a colour circle and by clicking on some of the colours you get the rgb, cmy and hex values. There is also a text that has to change its colour.

I could do it by just writing the values in the `document.getElementById("id").innertext` but I want to know if there is a better option using only html, css and js.

This is the image that we have to click on in order to get the colour values. (http://www.castelligasse.at/Werbetechnik/Farben/Farbkreis.gif)

```js
function updateData(colour) {

  switch (colour) {
    case "red":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#ff0000";
      break;
    case "green":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "green";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#00ff00";
      break;
    case "blue":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "blue";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#0000ff";
      break;
    case "cyan":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "cyan";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#00ffff";
      break;
    case "magenta":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "magenta";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#ff00ff";
      break;
    case "yellow":
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = "yellow";
      document.getElementById("red").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("green").innerText = "255";
      document.getElementById("blue").innerText = "0";
      document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = "#ffff00";
      break;
    default:
      alert("Error!");
  }

}
```

```html
<p id="text">
  This text has to be changed in the selected colour. <br>
</p>

<!--Color-circle image-->
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.castelligasse.at/Werbetechnik/Farben/Farbkreis.gif" usemap="#colourcircle">

  <map name="colourcircle">
    <area shape="poly" coords="13,117, 67,131, 66,169, 14,182, 10,148" alt="Red" href="javascript: updateData('red')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="253,53, 274,83, 285,108, 234,122, 215,91" alt="Gren" href="javascript: updateData('green')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="178,233, 210,214, 248,251, 224,269, 193,283" alt="Blue" href="javascript: updateData('blue')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="235,175, 285,189, 273,219, 254,244, 216,208" alt="Cyan" href="javascript: updateData('cyan')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="16,190, 68,176, 87,208, 49,246, 31,222, 17,190" alt="Magenta" href="javascript: updateData('magenta')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="117,13, 149,8, 182,12, 169,65, 132,66" alt="Yellow" href="javascript: updateData('yellow')">
   </map>
</div>

<div id="data">
  <table id="rgb">
    <th>Ihre gewählte Farbe in RGB</th>
    <tr>
      <td>ROT:</td>
      <td id="red">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GRÜN:</td>
      <td id="green">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BLAU:</td>
      <td id="blue">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="rgbhex">#000000:</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="cmy">
    <th>Ihre gewählte Farbe in CMY</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Cyan:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magenta:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blau:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#000000:</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be very good and reasonable refactors to this code. One of them is to separate the data from your code. You can use a JavaScript object to define the relationship between a color and its components (RGB values, hex value etc.).

This way, you can completely eliminate the need of the `switch...case` statements. Following is a working demo:

```js
// This is the color configuration object which defines the relationship between a color string and its respective RGB combination values with hex
var colorMap = {
  red: {
    red: 255,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0,
    hex: '#ff0000'
  },
  green: {
    red: 0,
    green: 255,
    blue: 0,
    hex: '#00ff00'
  }
  // ... And so on
};

function updateData(colour) {
  // Search for the config based on colour
  var config = colorMap[colour];

  if (!config) {
    // Show error if config is not found
    alert('error');
  } else {
    // Update the HTML components if config is found
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = colour;
    document.getElementById("red").innerText = config['red'];
    document.getElementById("green").innerText = config['green'];
    document.getElementById("blue").innerText = config['blue'];
    document.getElementById("rgbhex").innerText = config['hex'];
  }

}
```

```html
<p id="text">
  This text has to be changed in the selected colour. <br>
</p>

<!--Color-circle image-->
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.castelligasse.at/Werbetechnik/Farben/Farbkreis.gif" usemap="#colourcircle">

  <map name="colourcircle">
    <area shape="poly" coords="13,117, 67,131, 66,169, 14,182, 10,148" alt="Red" href="javascript: updateData('red')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="253,53, 274,83, 285,108, 234,122, 215,91" alt="Gren" href="javascript: updateData('green')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="178,233, 210,214, 248,251, 224,269, 193,283" alt="Blue" href="javascript: updateData('blue')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="235,175, 285,189, 273,219, 254,244, 216,208" alt="Cyan" href="javascript: updateData('cyan')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="16,190, 68,176, 87,208, 49,246, 31,222, 17,190" alt="Magenta" href="javascript: updateData('magenta')">
    <area shape="poly" coords="117,13, 149,8, 182,12, 169,65, 132,66" alt="Yellow" href="javascript: updateData('yellow')">
   </map>
</div>

<div id="data">
  <table id="rgb">
    <th>Ihre gewählte Farbe in RGB</th>
    <tr>
      <td>ROT:</td>
      <td id="red">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GRÜN:</td>
      <td id="green">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BLAU:</td>
      <td id="blue">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="rgbhex">#000000:</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="cmy">
    <th>Ihre gewählte Farbe in CMY</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Cyan:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magenta:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blau:</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#000000:</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Just keep adding as much colors you want and those will work as long as the value of `colour` is valid.